# Diophantine equation $ \frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{c}{a+b} = n $ computable?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, computability

We try to find positive integer solutions (or decide if there are any) for

$$ \frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{c}{a+b} = n $$

for any given positive integer n.

In the [first answer](https://qr.ae/pGWmEs) at https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y+z-+-frac-y-z+x-+-frac-z-x+y-4 Alon Amit seems to claim that this problem is uncomputable, without proof or reasoning.

> This is a striking example of the way diophantine equations with tiny coefficients can have enormous solutions. This isn’t merely awe-inspiring, it is profound. The negative solution of Hilbert’s 10th problem means that the growth of the solutions as the coefficients get larger is an uncomputable function, for if it were computable, we would have had a simple algorithm for solving diophantine equations, and there isn’t one (simple or complex). Here, the correspondence 4→ 80-digit numbers, 178→ hundreds-of-millions-digit numbers and 896→ trillions of digits gives us a glimpse into the first few tiny steps of that monstrous, uncomputable function. Tweak the numbers in your equation, and the solutions promptly exceed anything that fits in our puny little universe. What a wonderfully sneaky little equation.

If it's indeed the case, that would indeed explain why these solutions are so big (not necessary for n=4, but from a given n).

I wonder, if it's true?

Comment: Yes, it is easy for a Diophantine equation to have a solution, which is too big to compute explicitly. There is the link to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227713/estimating-the-size-of-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation/227722#comment562414_227760), where you can see that the smallest solution can be huge (but not always uncomputable). For example, the smallest solution for  $\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b} = 4 $ is [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nLm7B.jpg).

Comment: Also  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278747/is-the-set-of-integers-of-the-form-a-bcb-acc-ab-computable?noredirect=1&lq=1) your question has been asked already.

Comment: Technical point: a problem is "uncomputable" if there can be no algorithm that finds a solution. a problem is "computationally infeasible" if it cannot be solved using physically practicable resources. These two concepts are not the same.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's the first time I see something like this. I don't understand anything because it's not elementary number theory. But the question interests me a lot.  From the link you gave, I learned this: We can prove mathematically, for example, that there is a solution set for $n=4$.So, how is the solution itself found? Like the Discrete Logarithm problem? We know the solution exists. But can't we find it directly?  Just trial and error?Because a large numbers looks like a discrete logarithm problem to me.  We cannot solve it directly. Need to do trial and error? Am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @lonestudent In general this is very difficult. [This arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.02148.pdf) has some more details how to construct such solutions in some cases. You will need to accept some facts on elliptic curves, but I think it will become clear what you have asked. Also [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-226/S0025-5718-99-01068-6/S0025-5718-99-01068-6.pdf) gives some methods for computation, starting with "brute force" even.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can I ask one last question?  No one on earth will ever be able to solve this simple equation with elementary number theory techniques, do I understand right?

Comment: A slight remark about the statement with our universe. The observable universe is finite , but the universe has no limits in time and space although the big bang theory claims this. What I wonder : Are there undecidable cases (where there is no solution, but we cannot prove it) ? Or can they just be too difficult for practical computations ? As pointed out, this does NOT mean that they are uncomputable.